# How can I combat SMTP Header Manipulation in PHP?

Tags: php, email, header, smtp

I've been handed some code that handles email forms on a client website. Here is the code.

```
<?php

    $not_found = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/404";

        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {
                if($_POST && isset($_POST['emailForm'])) {

                        require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

                        $site_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
                        $from_email = $_POST['FromEmail'];
                        $first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];
                        $to_email = $_POST['ToEmail'];
                        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);
                        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

                        if($_POST['emailForm'] == 'share') {

                                $subject = $first_name . ' wants to share some info about acne treatment';

                                $email_body = file_get_contents('templates/share.html');
                                $email_body = str_replace(
                                                                        array('[BASEURL]', '[SENDER NAME]'),
                                                                        array($site_url, $first_name),
                                                                        $email_body
                                                                );

                                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
                                        ->setFrom($from_email)
                                        ->setTo($to_email)
                                    ->setBody($email_body);
                                $message->addPart($email_body, 'text/html');

                        }

                        if($_POST['emailForm'] == 'ddg') {
                                $file_name = 'pdf/Dermatologist_Discussion_Guide.pdf';
                                $subject = 'Your Dermatologist Discussion Guide';
                                $email_body = file_get_contents('templates/ddg.html');
                                $email_body = str_replace(
                                                                        array('[BASEURL]'),
                                                                        array($site_url),
                                                                        $email_body
                                                                );

                                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
                                        ->setFrom($from_email)
                                        ->setTo($to_email)
                                        ->setBody($email_body);
                                $message->addPart($email_body, 'text/html');
                                $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file_name));
                        }

                        if($mailer->send($message)){
                                $success = true;
                        } else {
                                $success = false;
                        }

                } else {
                        header('Location: ' . $not_found);
                }
                echo json_encode($success);
        } else {
                header('Location: ' . $not_found);
        }
?>
```

Apparently it doesn't protect against SMTP Header Manipulation. I looked at OWASP and they listed how the exploit is done but didn't list any countermeasures. Can anyone help out or link some resources? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4):

Answer: setting SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records.